# Node.JS + MongoDB aggregation Find array in array from DataBase in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a Model in MongoDB which include an array(category) which has an array(picture) inside it.
Shirt Model looks like this:

```
{ _id: 100, category: [ { name: 'CatName', _id: 101, picture: [Object] } ] }
```

And my Picture Array looks like this:

```
 [ { path: 'p1', _id: 102 },
   { path: 'p2', _id: 103 } ] }
```

I Pass 3 variables

1. main array id which is **100** (var1)
2. category name which is **CatName**  (var2)
3. picture id which is **102**    (var3)

I want to GET an array which looks like:

```
{ _id: 100, category: [ { name: 'CatName', _id: 101,
                          picture: [ { path: 'p1', _id: 102 }]  
                        } ]
}
```

What I have tried is this:

```
Shirt.find(   {_id: var1} ,  
{category: { $and:[ { name: var2 } , { picture: {$elemMatch: {_id: var3}}}  ] }}  )
.exec(function(err, product) {
    console.log('Result  ' + product );
    res.jsonp(product);
});
```

But the Result I receive is Undefined for First Code

Second Code That I tried:

```
Shirt.find( {_id: var1} ,
            {category: {$elemMatch: { name: var2,picture: {$elemMatch: {_id: var3} }}} }  )
```

And Result from second code filter the array for **var1** and **var2**
But it contain the whole picture array which means it does not filter **var3**

1. What is the correct code to find what I want?
2. Is this a correct approach for a Shopping Website database Or you have a better suggestion?
3. Am I applying Parent and Child Database Correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of $elemMatch use "picture._id"

Comment: It does not work.
and I dont think DOT is defined in mongodb find operation

Answer (score 0):

Following mongo query will give you expected result:

```
db.collection.find({
    "category": {
    $elemMatch: {
        "name": "CatName",
        "picture": {
            $elemMatch: {
                "_id": 102
            }
        }
    }
    }
})
```

**You need to convert it in node.js format.**

Following format may help you. **Not Tested**

```
collection.find({
    _id: "" // add your match Id here} ,  
        {
            category: {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "name": "CatName",
                    "picture": {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            "_id": 102
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, product) {
    console.log('Result  ' + product);
    res.jsonp(product);
    });
```

**AFTER EDIT QUESTION**

You should use [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to get required values. Query will be like following -

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: '$category'
}, {
    $unwind: '$category.picture'
}, {
    $match: {
    _id: 100, // add here your var1 variable instead of 100
    'category.name': 'CatName', // add here your var2 variable instead of 'CatName'
    'category._id': 102, //add your match id here if any otherwise remove this condition
    'category.picture._id': 102 //add your var3 instead of 102
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: '$category.name',
    'name': {
        $first: '$category.name'
    },
    'picture': {
        '$push': '$category.picture'
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: I just Update my question with your code But I receive the whole picture array

Comment: Answer is according to your question before edit. So you need to only matched field from picture array, right?

Comment: If you see the second code that I tried is exactly like your
And the result include the whole picture array But I want it to return only one picture

Comment: That 100 is not Category._id
Could You write it again with var1 , var2 and var3
That 100 is Shirt._id

Comment: @SaeedNode.js You can add any condition in match. I just added it as an example. you can change it

Comment: and Which one whould be the result that I can print on Console.log?

Comment: @SaeedNode.js - Can u check discussion please??